# How can I prevent that the points double up?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a small quiz on c#- windows form. But the problem is that every time I click on the check button the points double up like from 2 to 4 and so on. How can I prevent this? As I am "beginner" I don't really have any clue. I think this could be solve with radio button but my task is to mix with radio and check button.

Code:

```
int right=0;

if (richtig.Checked && !falsch.Checked && !falsch1.Checked && !falsch2.Checked)
{
    right++;
}
if (richtig1.Checked && !falsch3.Checked && !falsch4.Checked && !falsch5.Checked)
{
    right++;
}
if (richtig2.Checked && !falsch6.Checked && !falsch7.Checked && !falsch8.Checked)
{
    right++;
}
if (richtig3.Checked && !falsch9.Checked && !falsch10.Checked && !falsch11.Checked)
{
    right++;

}

if (right < 2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your have less than the half point! " +right+ " /5");
    wrong.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have" + right +"/5 correct.");
    correct.Visible = true;
}
```

The windows form picture:

[image: Picture]

Comment: Hi Bisho, welcome to stackoverflow? Have you debugged your code? is it going in two different if conditions. This the place where you are incrementing `right` variable.

Comment: Where do you declare the variable right? If it is not in the event handler (CheckButton_Click), and is a class member of the form, this sill happen. Just reset the `right` variable after displaying the MessageBox, `right = 0;`

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thank you so much i declared the variable outsie the CheckButton_Click so the value didnt reset. Now working very well

Comment: @OguzOzgul How can you tell where this `CheckButton_Click` is from the code posted here/?

Comment: @HereticMonkey the name may not be the exact name of the event handler but isn't it obvious that this code runs in an event hander or a method invoked from inside it, (OP: "every time I click on the check button"), so it does not matter if it is CheckButton_Click or GesamtBewertung_Click, the OP will get it. The unintended increase in `right` variable tells us that it is not declared inside this scope. Guessing? Maybe, but this is the comments section yet.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I was just curious if you knew something the rest of us didn't. It has happened before where I've received responses like "I'm in the same class as the OP" :).

Comment: Oh no, :) I am too old for that :)